# Initialization of Member variables vs Member functions

Tags: c++

Trying to compile the following using c++11 standards fails with an error:

```
class test{
 public:
 int getId(){
   return id;
 }
 constexpr int id = 5;
};
```

`non-static data member cannot be constexpr;`.

I assume the above happens since the class `test` doesn't exist yet at compile time.

However, defining `constexpr int id = 5;` under `getId(){` compiles just fine.
Is the function `getId` available during compile time? How can it be available if it's class doesn't exist yet?

Example 2:

```
class test{
 public:
 int getId(){
   constexpr int id = 5;
   return id;
 }
};
```

Comment: Is it your intent that `id` should be the same for _every_ object of type `test`, or should every object have a different `id`?

Comment: Yes you should make it `static constexpr` if you provide an `in-class initializer`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the function is available at compile-time. And you can confirm that by making it a `constexpr` function as shown below. You could instead declare the function `constexpr static`, since it does not need access to any non-static members.

```
class test {
public:
    constexpr int getId() {
        constexpr int id = 5;
        return id;
    }
};
```

Comment: How is the function available at compile time if the class itself doesn't exist yet?

Comment: A constexpr or static function is not a member of a (non-static) instance, but of the class. Hence it can be called via the class like `test::getId()` instead of via an instance like `myTest.getId()` or `pTest->getId()`.

Comment: No but how about my `Example 2` above? `getId` is not static but a variable under is, how does this work?

Comment: In that case, the variable is known at compile time, but the non-static, non-constexpr function is evaluated at run time. Unless the function is going to do something besides return a constexpr value, then it should be marked `constexpr static`.